# Symfony2: Can I use same entities for symfony 2.0 and symfony 2.1?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I have a Bundle containing some entities and resources shared by two apps in diferent hosts. That entities were coded using symfony 2.0. Now I want to upgrade one of apps to symfony 2.1 and the other continue using symfony 2.0. Is this posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony 2.0 and 2.1 use different Doctrine versions. It's not really a question about Symfony but rather about Doctrine (which is a separate project).

You should check if there were any backwards incompatible changes in Doctrine. But I think you'll be fine. If you have a test suite, it should catch all the behavior changes.